# how to add two values in ng-model? subtraction is working fine

Tags: angularjs

I'm currently practicing some basic stuff of angularjs. What is the proper or the correct way? I'm confused about this. Can someone make it correct?

you can test it here...
http://plnkr.co/edit/xJNWVY6B298eZ46FauNh?p=preview

code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.3"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <input type="text" ng-model="vm.one"><br><br>
    <input type="text" ng-model="vm.two"><br><br>
    <input type="text" value="{{ vm.one + vm.two }}">

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: see my answer it will solve your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are adding string values. I would try converting them to numbers first:

`<input type="text" value="{{ +vm.one + +vm.two }}">`

[Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/Hcfso60DZakVC8uGDWOr?p=preview)

Comment: thanks :) that was easy hahah, but i have 1 more question.. how to calculate it with two decimal places?

Comment: You can add angular `number` filter. It will round up values to the specified decimal places `{{ +vm.one + +vm.two | number:2 }}`

Comment: what if user enter string ? it will give you NAN

Comment: I will pick the one who is the quickest response because both of you is correct :) i hope that would be fair for both of you :)

Comment: Regarding invalid values, depends on how you do error handling in your project. One way is indeed using `type="number"` - to get browser validation. I just noticed that angular `number` filter shows empty value instead of NaN.

Answer (score 1):

try this one http://plnkr.co/edit/UuayjLUscGIdLUN3YIxL?p=preview

```
<input type="number" ng-model="vm.one"><br><br>
<input type="number" ng-model="vm.two"><br><br>
<input type="text" value="{{ vm.one+ vm.two }}">
```

Comment: I will pick the one who is the quickest response because both of you is correct :) i hope that would be fair for both of you :)

Comment: @Jayrex in below answer  if you enter string then what ?

Comment: it will give you a NAN

Comment: so handle properly  :D but if you use number type then it will not allow to enter string so your problem will be solved